# Newer versions of chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webapps

I've been wondering why the ubuntu's version of chromium is still on 25 -- from lucid up until  raring -- while the current stable version is 28. The only reason I use chromium is to use the web apps integration.

PS : I have tried to use the web apps integration on another version of chromium -- not google chrome -- which is 28 then it seems that some features I use was lost while using other version than 25.

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot to tell you I use the 13.04 version and also the development branch 13.10. My question was : Why does ubuntu doesn't update the package in the repository to the current stable version?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` recently? Chromium stable v28 has been available from the Software Center for the past couple of days. There's no need to access any ppa as of now to get v28.

Comment: Re. 13.10, see the currently last comment here.

Comment: too localized to a particular point in time. Actually, the question is incorrect because Chromium 28 is available. 

Comment: 28 is indeed the current version on the official repositories in `precise-updates` (earlier only on `security.ubuntu.com` though). `$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser` shows 
`Candidate: 28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.12.04.2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages` Maybe packages.ubuntu.com is a bit out of date on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update for Chromium was released within the last 24 hours for 12.04. I would expect the same for 13.04.

You may want to check your Update Manager, or run `sudo apt-get update` from your command line.

As of today, I am running Chromium Version 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 12.04 (28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.12.04.2

Comment: According to the `www.packages.ubuntu.com`, the version of the chromium is 25 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.04.1).

Comment: Nevermind, I run `apt-get update` and found the new version.